# Why is docker images list empty?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to see a list of images in my docker instance, but I keep getting an empty list.

I run

```
docker run busybox:latest echo hello
```

It prints `hello`. I run

```
docker images list --all
```

it prints

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

The same thing happens if I try `docker load -i myimage.tar` and list. Why isn't it showing any images?

---

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 22:51:12 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 22:50:04 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try

`docker images`

I think the docker client is trying to filter by token `list` and therefore is not finding any images with this name criteria.

Comment: On a newly installed docker build a dotnet compose solution, we see 2 pulled images for sdk and runtime but if we remove this 2 images somehow like prune they get upset :) and won't get back on next build. But if we build again they get pulled in the background (though we can't see them with --all) but if we run "docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0" it says "xxxxxxxxxxxx: Already exists" 8 times and voila the image is visible there. (Docker 4.19.0)

Comment: `docker image prune` only removes unused dangling images: `The docker image prune command allows you to clean up unused images. By default, docker image prune only cleans up dangling images. A dangling image is one that is not tagged and is not referenced by any container.`. Perhaps there is more to it than prune doing wrong.

Comment: Probably I did somthing wrong in the Dockerfile that ruined the images (I was practicing). My docker desktop (windows) had strange behavior when I was removing the dangling images manually. Anyway to shrink the ext4.vhdx and have a clean docker I used "Purge data" and now everything is right, thank you.

Answer (score 48):

`docker images` - Will list all the images.

`docker image ls` - is same as "docker images"

`docker images ls` - here "ls" acts as filter.

Comment: My god this is terrible UX

Comment: Seriously, unbelievable..

Comment: I can't believe the inconsistency between `image`, `container`, `network`, and `volume`.  Why have `docker ps -a` when you could have `docker container ls`? Why have the third listing syntax of `docker images`?

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative answer is to enter `docker image ls`

Comment: this actually worked for me, and using `docker image ls -a`  gives images in private repo if configured

Answer (score 0):

`docker images` and `docker image ls` is same but `docker images ls` is extension of first command and ls is other argument to first command, unfortunately no output is defined in docker default commands.

so you can use any of below command for listing images.

```
docker images

docker image ls
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such confusion, docker introduced management commands.

Management commands avoid confusion and there is a consistency. For instance `docker inspect` is a vague command and one has to specify either a <container_name/id> or <network_name/id>.

With management commands, one can be sure that the command is related to one of the images,containers,networks or volumes.

To get the entire set of management commands, try `docker --help` or simply `docker` in your terminal.

Try `docker image --help` to get the entire set of commands for images.